# My site doesn't detect viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a site called Healthot. It's a responsive site, with the meta viewport tags and the media queries. The problem is that the site only adapts when I resize Chrome's window of my Mac. When i enter the site in a mobile phone, like iPhone 5, it's doesn't scale.

The site is http://www.healthot.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information *to diagnose* the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) _in the question itself_.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a meta tag in the head, which I don't seem to find on your site.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Yeah in the code it's shows <?php if( wp_is_mobile()) { ?><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"><?php } ?> But i think that the function is not working properly... What can i do?

Comment: I think you should just keep the viewport meta in your head, shouldn't be a problem for your desktop experience.

Comment: Okay but it shows me too scaled (zoomed), how i can fix?

Comment: Updated the viewport, if you would be so kind to test it... :)

Comment: It's happens the same... Check this, when i enter it shows: https://www.dropbox.com/s/27o9ubygfl4ci3w/Foto%2016-04-14%2018%2058%2005.png When i zoomed out it shows perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I dont see

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 " />
```

in firebug.

Try to add all year meta tags in top of the head. Sometimes it is can be important

Answer (score 0):

From where is this coming?

```
<script async="" type="text/javascript" src="http://whos.amung.us/pingjs/?k=xd69ovuycv2g&amp;t=Healthot%20%7C%20Fitness%20control.%20Better%20bodies.&amp;c=s&amp;y=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F23115237%2Fmy-site-doesnt-detect-viewport&amp;a=0&amp;r=7773"></script>
```

And add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Ok i add this and i think that it worked, but the problem was that this function is doesn't work properly:  <?php if( wp_is_mobile()) { ?><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"> <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"><?php } ?>

Comment: Your if statement isn't a function and it doesn't matter. Just put the tag in there and leave it there - always. A conditional meta tag is the last thing you need to worry about.

Comment: Okay, Check this, when i enter in iPhone it shows: http://https://www.dropbox.com/s/27o9ubygfl4ci3w/Foto%2016-04-14%2018%2058%2005.png When i zoomed out it shows perfect.